# How do I instantiate an object with the parameter from list in Vb?

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, oop, menu

In the form, I have created a menu with all the items that the user can choose from. I have then added all those items in a list with prices and name of each one (using the class 'MenuItem').

```
Dim menu As New List(Of MenuItem) From
 {
     New MenuItem With {.Name = "Burger", .Cost = 2.0 * txtburger.Text},
     New MenuItem With {.Name = "wrap", .Cost = 2.0 * txtwrap.Text},
     New MenuItem With {.Name = "Parmesan", .Cost = 2.5 * txtparmesan.Text},
     New MenuItem With {.Name = "Stirfry", .Cost = 3.0 * txtstirfry.Text},
     New MenuItem With {.Name = "pitta", .Cost = 2.5 * txtpitta.Text},
```

In the class 'Orders' I then made another list in which these items will be added to when the user selects items.

```
Public Property Items As List(Of MenuItem) = New List(Of MenuItem)
```

In order to add the 'menu' items in this list, I created a method which takes each item as a parameter.

```
Public Sub AddItem(ByVal item As MenuItem)

        Items.Add(item)

    End Sub
```

But I'm not sure how to instantiate an object from this so every time the user creates an order, all the items user selects from menu are added to the list. (I can then use the list to calculate total etc)

Like how do I pass the parameter in the method for each item? and If I have to instantiate multiple objects for each item that is selected, how would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

The `MenuItem` instances are created when you created your `menu` List. You can add them to a separate list, an `order` list:

```
Private order As New List(Of MenuItem)
```

If you use buttons on your form, one for each `MenuItem`, you can add the `MenuItem` instances to your `order` List in the button click event handler:

```
Private Sub BurgerButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BurgerButton.Click

    Dim menuItem As MenuItem
    menuItem = menu.Find(Function(item As MenuItem) item.Name = "Burger")

    order.Add(menuItem)

End Sub
```

This is a pretty simple way to do things. You should consider using the Button's Tag property to store the `MenuItem` name and have a single Button Click handler:

```
Private Sub ButtonClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BurgerButton.Click, WrapButton.Click

    Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim menuItem As MenuItem
    menuItem = Menu.Find(Function(item As MenuItem) item.Name = button.Tag)

    order.Add(menuItem)

End Sub
```